# removeEventListener in forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, removeeventlistener

Friends!

How in JS to hang such a handler on all the buttons of the collection, so that when each of them is clicked, something happens, and the handler is removed from all the buttons in the collection?
I managed to make it so that it is removed only from the one I click on (while the class is removed from everyone):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.string').forEach((field, i, fields) => {
  const listen = () => {
    const res = document.createElement('div');
    res.textContent = field.textContent;
    document.getElementById('container').append(res);

    fields
      .forEach((field, i, fields) => {
        field.classList.remove('bright');
        field.removeEventListener('click', listen);
      });
  };

  field.addEventListener('click', listen);
});
```

https://codepen.io/andreymi/pen/RwMOvOq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code isnt working because the listen function get recreated for each element

```
var fields=document.querySelectorAll('.string');

const listen = () => {
  const res = document.createElement('div');
  res.textContent = this.textContent;     // <- note 'this' keyword
  document.getElementById('container').append(res);

  fields.forEach((field, i, fields) => {
    field.classList.remove('bright');
    field.removeEventListener('click', listen);
    console.log('remove',i);
  });
};

fields.forEach((field, i, fields) => {
  console.log('add',i);
  field.addEventListener('click', listen);
});
```

Comment: It's works. Thank you. The only thing - I had to replace `this` to `e.target`. ```const listen = (e) => {
  const res = document.createElement('div');
  res.textContent = e.target.textContent;```

Comment: ah yh, the arrow function doesnt have this, arguments ... [mdn arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a listener to all and then removing a listener from all, how about adding a single listener to a container element with event delegation, which can then be removed easily by referencing the function name again?

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.string');
const flex = document.querySelector('.flex');
flex.addEventListener('click', function handler(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.string')) {
    return;
  }
  flex.removeEventListener('click', handler);
  const res = document.createElement('div');
  res.textContent = e.target.textContent;
  document.getElementById('container').append(res);
  for (const button of buttons) {
    button.classList.remove('bright');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background: #808080;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1em;
}

.string {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 80px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.bright {
  background: #58afd1;
}
```

```html
<body class="wrap">
  <div class="flex">
    <button type='button' class="string bright">1</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">2</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">3</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">5</button>
  </div>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>
```

Or perhaps have the buttons inherit their style from their container.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.string');
const flex = document.querySelector('.flex');
flex.addEventListener('click', function handler(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.string')) {
    return;
  }
  flex.removeEventListener('click', handler);
  const res = document.createElement('div');
  res.textContent = e.target.textContent;
  document.getElementById('container').append(res);
  flex.classList.remove('bright');
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background: #808080;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1em;
}

.string {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 80px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.bright .string {
  background: #58afd1;
}
```

```html
<body class="wrap">
  <div class="flex bright">
    <button type='button' class="string bright">1</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">2</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">3</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">5</button>
  </div>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>
```

That works for the code in your question, but if the code you're actually using doesn't match what's in your question, then:

- If your buttons have child elements, the target may be one of those child elements, and not one of the buttons, and so to check that the clicked element is a descendant of a button, change to `e.target.closest('.string')`
- If, in addition to the above, you may have a `.string` element that's a container of the `.flex`, clicks on the `.flex` that aren't on the buttons will be registered. If the HTML you're actually using has that, then check that the `.string` is a descendant by searching through only descendants of the `.flex` container with [`.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains).
  starting from the `.flex` container

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.string');
const flex = document.querySelector('.flex');
flex.addEventListener('click', function handler(e) {
  if (!flex.contains(e.target.closest('.string'))) {
    return;
  }
  flex.removeEventListener('click', handler);
  const res = document.createElement('div');
  res.textContent = e.target.textContent;
  document.getElementById('container').append(res);
  flex.classList.remove('bright');
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background: #808080;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1em;
}

.string {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 80px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.bright .string {
  background: #58afd1;
}
```

```html
<body class="wrap">
  <div class="flex bright">
    <button type='button' class="string bright">1</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">2</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">3</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">5</button>
  </div>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>
```

- If some of your child elements of `.flex` aren't buttons, and some descendants of those elements also have the `flex` class, and those `.flex` descendants also have some `.string` descendants of their own, then to guard against the possibility of selecting one of those buttons instead of one of the immediate children buttons, after selecting the closest `.string`, check that its parent element is the `flex` the listener was attached to.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.string');
const flex = document.querySelector('.flex');
flex.addEventListener('click', function handler(e) {
  const button = e.target.closest('.string');
  if (!button || !button.matches('.string') || !button.parentElement === flex) {
    return;
  }
  flex.removeEventListener('click', handler);
  const res = document.createElement('div');
  res.textContent = e.target.textContent;
  document.getElementById('container').append(res);
  flex.classList.remove('bright');
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background: #808080;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1em;
}

.string {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 80px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.bright .string {
  background: #58afd1;
}
```

```html
<body class="wrap">
  <div class="flex bright">
    <button type='button' class="string bright">1</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">2</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">3</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="string bright">5</button>
  </div>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>
```

But if the HTML structure you have is what's actually in your question, you may consider there to be no need to complicate things.

Comment: Instead of `e.target.matches('.string')` it would be better to `e.currentTarget.contains(e.target.closest('.string'))`. Currently this would fail if `.string` has children: https://jsfiddle.net/tmubceh9 vs https://jsfiddle.net/tmubceh9/1  (Also it might be worth it to mention to the `signal` option that can be passed to `addEventListener`, delegation is the correct move here, but it might help in other, related, situations. Oh and it's also probably better to `this.removeEventListener()` or `e.currentTarget` instead of querying a fresh and possibly different `document.querySelector('.flex')`.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Unfortunately, in this case, this method is not suitable, because in fact I need to hang the handler not on all fields, but on those dynamically selected by condition `const fields = document.querySelectorAll('.string').filter(...);`

Comment: @andreymishchenko If you need to only match a particular type of `.string` elements, then change their attributes when turning them on and off, then change the selector to look for those attributes. For example, do `string.classList.add('no')` and then just change `.matches('.string')` to `.matches('.string:not(.no)')` and then it will exclude elements with both `string` and `no`.

Comment: You're right - it looks more complicated than @matt answer - but it also works. I'll remember)